# select count with 2 conditions

Tags: mysql, random, time

I have 2 tables, **med** and **viz** with the following structure:

**med**

```
CREATE TABLE med 
(id_med INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name_m VARCHAR(50),
surname_m VARCHAR(50),
spec VARCHAR(50),
UNIQUE (surname_m,name_m));
```

**viz**

```
CREATE TABLE viz
(id_m INT NOT NULL,
id_p INT  NOT NULL,
id_c INT  NOT NULL,
dt DATETIME)
```

I need a select query that would give the full name from med where count of id_p<250 and year from dt is 2010.
The following query gives me a bad result :

```
select count(id_p)<250 as no_p,
(select distinct concat(name_m,' ',surname_m) from med where id_med=id_m) as fullname
from viz where year(dt)=2010;
```

Comment: Define bad result.

Comment: ur are right about `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`. im new to mysql(4 weeks on) and i'm loving this website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT concat(m.name_m,' ',m.surname_m) AS fullname, COUNT(v.id_p)
FROM med m JOIN viz v
ON m.id_med = v.id_m
WHERE year(dt)=2010
GROUP BY m.id_med
HAVING COUNT(v.id_p) < 250
```

Comment: needs to be `LEFT JOIN` else you wont get results for 0 :P

Comment: @Sujeet Sinha i think i can't. it says i dont have the reputation. this was my first question. :(